# How to perform the map.delete method based on a condition (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, maps, key

I have two maps, how will I be able to delete the entries in map 1 whose keys aren't present in map b? (The values don't matter). Here's what I've tried so far, but when I return map 1, the "excessobject" key is still being returned.

```
const map1 = new Map () 
map1.set = (object1, 1) 
map1.set = (object2, 2) 
map1.set = (excessobject, 3) 

const map2 = new Map ()
map2.set = (object1, 1) 
map2.set = (object2, 2) 

for (const key of map1.keys()) 
  map1.delete(!map2.has(key))

map1;
```

Comment: "how will I be able to delete the entries in map 1 ..." map1 does not contain a single entry in your snippet; neither does map2. `map1.set = (object1, 1)` and `map1.set(object1, 1)` do very very very differrent things. Both valid actions in JS, not reasonable but valid, but only the latter one adds items to your map.

Answer (score 0):

So first you have your syntax wrong since for setting a value inside a `Map()` you need to do it like `map.set('something',value)`. Here you have more about [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map); also for deleting you have to pass the `Key`, you were passing the `false/true` from `!map2.has(key)`

```js
let object1 = {test:1}
let object2 = {test:2}
let excessobject = {test:3};
const map3 = new Map () 
map3.set(object1, 1) 
map3.set(object2, 2) 
map3.set(excessobject, 3) 
console.log(map3.size)
const map4 = new Map ()
map4.set(object1, 1) 
map4.set(object2, 2) 
for (const key of map3.keys()){
  map3.delete(!map4.has(key) ? key : '')
} 

console.log(map3.size)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at !map2.has(key).
That statement returns a Boolean which is probably not what you're looking for.

If you spread that out a little more, it should do what you want it to.

```
for (const key of map1.keys()){
  if (!(map2.has(key)){
    map1.delete(key)
  }
}
```